# how can get the values from input field?

Tags: reactjs, database

I manage to get the values from database to the text field. But now I want to get the values and update to database. But I can't get the text field values to update.

Below is my code. Can anyone help and give me any advice.
Not Sure, where I doing wrong.

> ```
> <TableBody>
>   {(() => {
>       let genericKey = Object.keys(genericStep2ResultList)[1];
>       var list = genericStep2ResultList[genericKey];
>       return list.map((result, index) => {
>           let col = Object.keys(result)
>           return (
>               <TableRow key={result.SERIAL_NO}>
>                   {inEditMode.status && inEditMode.rowKey === result.SERIAL_NO ? (
>                       <TableCell>
>                           <DoneAllOutlinedIcon 
>                               onClick={() =>
>                                   onSave()
>                               }
>                           >
>                               Save
>                           </DoneAllOutlinedIcon >
>                           <NotInterestedIcon
>                               onClick={() =>
>                                   onCancel()
>                               }
>                           >
>                               Cancel
>                           </NotInterestedIcon>
>                       </TableCell>
>                   ) : (
>                           <TableCell>
>                               <EditOutlinedIcon 
>                                   onClick={() => 
>                                       onEdit(result.SERIAL_NO)
>                                   }
>                           >
>                               Edit
>                               </EditOutlinedIcon >
>                       </TableCell>
>                   )}
>                   {col.map((val, index) => {
>                           return (
>                               inEditMode.status && inEditMode.rowKey === result.SERIAL_NO ? (
>                                   <TableCell key={index}>
>                                       <input type="text" value={result[col[index]]} 
>                                          onChange={(event) => setUnitPrice(event.target.value)}
>                                       />
>                                   </TableCell>
>                               ) : (
>                                   <TableCell key={index}>
>                                       {result[col[index]]}
>                                   </TableCell>
>                               )
>                           );
>                       }
>                       
>                   )}
>               </TableRow>
>           )
>       })
>   })()}
> </TableBody>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

> <input type="text" value={result[col[index]]} onChange={(event) =>
> setUnitPrice(event.target.value)} />

In this input field, instead of passing the value as `result[col[index]]`, instead pass a state variable. And, initialize that state variable with the value `result[col[index]]`. That way, the input string changes, the state variable will update.